# Sharepoint 2010 - Get All Group Names On Subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm completely new to SharePoint 2010 and I'm trying to get a report that looks like this.

Group Name | Subsite or Site Group is used | Group Creation Date | Group Owner

I tried using google for the last three days. So far, I didn't achieve anything.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to one of the web servers on which SharePoint is running, you can produce a report of that type through PowerShell, such as via the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.

```powershell
$web = get-spweb "http://examplesite/exampleweb"
$arr = @() 
$web.SiteGroups | %{ $obj = new-object psobject -property @{Name=$_.Name; ParentWeb=$_.ParentWeb; Owner=$_.Owner }; $arr += $obj; }
$arr | Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\SiteGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that this doesn't include the group creation date.

Comment: Thanks. But report is only showing usernames ? Did I got something wrong ?